# Wordpress download_url() with local files import

Tags: php, wordpress, image-uploading

I want to set post featured image from local stored picture, but I can't create temporary file on server.

When I try to do that:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

$url = ABSPATH . 'import/photos/test/test.jpg'; // DON"T WORK, BUT FILE EXISTS
// $url = 'http://example.com/import/photos/test/test.jpg'; - WORKS
$tmp = download_url( $url );
var_dump($tmp);
```

I have that error on tmp:

```
object(WP_Error)#11636 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["http_request_failed"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(46) "Предоставлен неверный URL." } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }
```

Path to stored file is correct. When if I try to import that file from web URL it upload correctly and shows me `string(20) "/tmp/test-jMHjga.tmp"`.

Why I can't use local server paths?

Answer (score 1):

Because download_url() uses the WP_Http class to get remote resources through HTTP protocol. So the path must be an URL.